# Python: adding columns to dataframe using calculated values from specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am pretty new to python and would like to start working in it and move away from excel. My problem is two fold:

First part is that I have a csv file which looks like this

```
   row 1: 52.78 52.52   53.2  51.98  53.22  50.85   51.44   52.38   52.21   52.09   51.5    51.92
   row2 : 6.89  5.47    5.8    5.89   6.56   5.69   5.48     4.9     6.39    5.12   3.61     4.48
   row3:  156   126    185     363     197    261    417     298      292    150    102     303
   row4:  0     0      0       0       0       0      0       0        0      0      0       0     
   row5:  0     3      5       8       0       0      10       0        12      0      13       0
    ...
    ...
    ...
  row195: 0     5      5      7       1       2      11       0        12      0      13       0
```

it goes on like this till row 195

I want to create new columns which start on row 4 and use the following formula:

the first column should be

```
    [(row3,column1)*(row4,column1)]+[(row3,column1)*(row101,column1)]
```

the second column should be

```
    [(row3,column2)*(row4,column2)]+[(row3,column2)*(row101,column2)]
```

it goes on like this till row 100 for all 12 columns

the formula in row 100 for the first column should be

```
   [(row3,column1)*(row98,column1)]+[(row3,column1)*(row195,column1)]
```

how do I go about doing this in Pandas?

The second part of my problem is that I have 365 different files with similar data (the values change per file but the format is the same) and I would like to apply this same formula in all the files.

Appreciate any help I can get

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use pandas like Excel if I understand it correctly.

If your dataset/dataframe is called df and you would like to append a new column. You would right something like:

`df['first_col']=float(df.iloc[2,0])*float(df.iloc[3,0])+float(df.iloc[2,0])*float(df.ilo[100,0])`

... and the same for the other 2 columns. Be aware that python starts counting from 0. Hence, your row 1 is actually row 0 and column 1 is column 0 etc. Hope this helps.